# Turi Create Error : 'module' object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, graphlab

I am trying to implement nearest neighbor classifier in Turi Create, however I am unsure of this error I am getting. This error occurs when I create the actual model. I am using python 3.6 if that helps.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/turi/turi.py", line 51, in <module>
    iris_cross()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/turi/turi.py", line 37, in iris_cross
    clf = tc.nearest_neighbor_classifier(train_data, target='4', features=features)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
import turicreate as tc
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import datasets

import time
import numpy as np

#Iris Classification Cross Validation
def iris_cross():
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    features = ['0','1','2','3']
    target = iris.target_names
    x = iris.data
    y = iris.target.astype(int)

    undata = np.column_stack((x,y))
    data = tc.SFrame(pd.DataFrame(undata))
    print(data)

    train_data, test_data = data.random_split(.8)

    clf = tc.nearest_neighbor_classifier(train_data, target='4', features=features)

    print('done')

iris_cross()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually call the `create()` method of the nearest_neighbor_classifier. See the [library API](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.nearest_neighbor_classifier.create.html).

Run the following line of code instead:

`clf = tc.nearest_neighbor_classifier.create(train_data, target='4', features=features)`